# I would like to keep my table's data type as date but I want my table to show date and time format in the same column

Tags: oracle, date, select

I would like to keep my table's data type as `date` but I want my table to show date and time in the same column.

This is what I have so far. How do I change the format? I use Oracle SQL.

```
insert into student 
  values 
  (001, 
   to_date('2018-02-02 21:05:18', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
  'Oriel Road Brisbane', 
   103, 
   2486675, 
   760024, 
  'fdg57690gmig'
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything; that column already contains both date and time. It is the front-end that is supposed to display it as you want. Here are some examples:

```
SQL> create table test (datum date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (datum) values (to_date('2018-02-02 21:05:18', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

DATUM
--------
02.02.18

SQL> select to_char(datum, 'hh24:mi:ss') only_time,
  2    to_char(datum, 'dd-mon-yy') date_format_1,
  3    to_char(datum, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') date_and_time
  4  from test;

ONLY_TIM DATE_FORMAT_1      DATE_AND_TIME
-------- ------------------ -------------------
21:05:18 02-vel-18          2018-02-02 21:05:18

SQL>
```

Which means: use `TO_CHAR` with appropriate format mask, if you use `SELECT` statement. If it is about e.g. Oracle Apex, Forms or Reports, modify item's format mask.

Alternatively, you may talk to DBA to change NLS settings for the whole database, or you can do it for your session:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select datum from test;

DATUM
-------------------
02.02.2018 21:05:18
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's `DATE` datatype does store the date *and time* - there is not date-only datatype in Oracle, unlike some other databases, such as MySQL, that has `DATE` and `DATETIME` datatypes.

Your code is correctly inserting a date/time value in the table.

When Oracle displays a date, it uses by default the format defined by parameter `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` (which, for your database, is probably something that does not include the time portion).

You ca either change the setting at session level:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';
```

Or you can use `to_char()` on the date column:

```
select to_char(mydatecol, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as mydatestring
from mytable
```